# sticky menu in a joomla site won't work

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, menu, sticky

I have the following website:

[website](http://biezen.byantoinette.nl/)

With the following JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('.menu-2-section').addClass('smallheader');
             }
             else {
                 $('.menu-2-section').removeClass('smallheader');
             }
        });
    });
```

In the CSS I will have then:

```
.smallheader {position: fixed; top: 0; z-index:150;}
```

I There must be something wrong with the code, but What?

Please, I need some help with this ;-)

Thanks!!!

Comment: The code you've provided is different to the code in your `template.js` file. On the live site, you're using `$('#body').addClass('smallheader');` so you can't scroll to the bottom of the page. Your `template.js` is also quite a bit of a mess. The top of the file already contains `jQuery(function($) {`, so there's absolutely no need to use `$(document).ready(function(){` anywhere else in that file

Comment: You are right. The provided code is not the same as in the site, because I was trying to get it right by myself. I trie to achieve the following: when I scroll past the menu (class .menu-2-section) the menu has to become sticky to the top. Obvious the code is not right. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you write in question is good, and works well.
Notice that you need to add 'smallheader' class to object you want to make static/fixed position, in your case it should be .menu-2-section

but for now, you can't see menu because it's hidden by #top div.

```
#top {
    background-color: #eda99d;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

you need to change z-index here to less then 150, or change z-index in .smallmenu to greater then 999

Comment: Thanks, Arek. That is solving my problem. a Hard lesson to check the order of z-index the next time!